# Is it possible to mine Ethereum with the MultiMiner app?

Tags: mining, windows

Are there any pools that are compatible with MultiMiner? It can mine coins with Groestl,Keccak,Lyra 2RE,Neo Scrypt,Quark,Scrypt,Scrypt Jane,Scrypt N,SHA256,X11,X13,X14 and X15 algorithms and,while I dont know what algorithm Ethereum is,I know it is a PoW one and I wonder if any of those algorithms are what is used or can be used for mining ETH. Its such a pain to mine on Windows and there has to be a way to simplify it.

Comment: The algorith used by Ethereum PoW is called [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) and it seems it is not supported by MultiMiner.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully, MultiMiner may get an update to add Ethereum mining to its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Ethash & Ethereum are supported out-of-the-box in 4.2 of MultiMiner, but you can also add any additional algorithms as long as there is a CGMiner / BFGMiner / SGMiner fork that supports it.

- https://github.com/nwoolls/MultiMiner/releases
- https://github.com/nwoolls/MultiMiner/wiki/GPU-Algorithms